# decrease time until "C-x-" shows in echo area after pressing the keys

Tags: key-bindings, echo-area, keystrokes

When I try enter commands via `C-x`, it takes 1-2 seconds until the echo area shows this prefix key, as `C-x-`.   I'm quite new to Emacs, so this often confuses me, and I get lost.

The `ESC` key acts similar to this, so when I try to escape out of some half-entered command, I often end up looping pressing `ESC` and again after 1-2 second I see `ESC-` in the echo area.

Is there a way to decrease the time it takes to show a reaction in the echo area, am I doing something wrong, or is this somehow intended?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(setq echo-keystrokes 0.01)
```

will result in near-instantaneous echoing of the keystrokes. Alternatively, you could `customize` the variable (`M-x customize-variable RET echo-keystrokes`).

The variable determines the delay, in seconds, before echoing unfinished commands. If the value is 0, then do not echo at all (which is why you need to choose a very short delay, like 0.01 s).

Comment: works perfectly - are there any downsides/is there a reason for echo-keystrokes to be 1 initialy?

Comment: Not sure why — possibly to avoid clutter/over-verbosity when somebody presses the keys quickly. Neither the docstring of the variable (`C-h v`) nor the info manual list any downsides: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Echo-Area-Customization.html

Comment: great – thank you! 
will keep it .01sec then until I don't get lost anymore and eventually be annoyed by the clutter ^^

Comment: *"is there a reason for echo-keystrokes to be 1 initialy"* I would guess that it is a legacy setting. On a slow terminal you wouldn't want to waste bandwidth echoing commands that the user doesn't need to see.